# Variable used before being initialized in function

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a [ro sham bo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors) game. Functions in swift are different than what I have used before. I keep getting an error:

> Variable used before being initialized in function

What am I doing wrong?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class Result: UIViewController {
    var rval: Int?
    var chosen: Int?
    func determineWinner() -> Int {
        var returnval: Int
        if (chosen == rval){
            returnval = 2
        }
        else if (chosen == 1 && rval == 3){
            returnval = 1
        }
        else if (chosen == 1 && rval == 2){
            returnval = 0
        }
        else if (chosen == 2 && rval == 1){
            returnval = 1
        }
        return (returnval)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var wl: UILabel!

    @IBAction func PlayAgain(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print(chosen)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which variable?  Where in the code?

Comment: If none of the if statements match then returnval doesn't have a value, that is the reason for the error.

Comment: What if none of your if-else statements trigger in the function? What do you expect it to return in that circumstance? You need to provide some form of default value for `returnval`, or make your function return an optional.

Comment: Improved code formatting; clarified wording and provided a link to the game.

Comment: Remember to up vote and accept an answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Every possible path in the flow of a Swift program must have a defined returned value. In your case, if the `if`/`else if`/`else` sections are all skipped, leaving `returnval` unassigned. Thus, no valid value is being returned. Try this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit //space things out to be easier to read

class Result: UIViewController {

    var rval: Int? //these should have better names
    var chosen: Int?

    func determineWinner() -> Int {

        var returnval = -1 //needs a default value

        if (chosen == rval){
            returnval = 2
        }
        else if (chosen == 1 && rval == 3){
            returnval = 1
        }
        else if (chosen == 1 && rval == 2){
            returnval = 0
        }
        else if (chosen == 2 && rval == 1){
            returnval = 1
        }

        return returnval //don't put return value in brackets
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var wl: UILabel!

    @IBAction func PlayAgain(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print(chosen) 
    }
}
```

This is also a very good candidate for using pattern matching with [`switch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID127) statements. Here's what I think works beside, in conjunction with[Sean's suggestion.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37929733/3141234)

```
var determineWinner: Int? {

    guard let chosen = chosen, let rval = rval else {
        //handle error, either chosen or rval is nil
        return nil
    }

    switch ((chosen, rval)) {
    case let (x, y) where x == y: return 2
    case (1, 3): return 1
    case (1, 2): return 0
    case (2, 1): return 1

    default:
        print("handle default case here")
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, to use optionals into the `switch` clause you need to put something like this `case (Optional<Int>.Some(1), Optional<Int>.Some(3)): return 1` into the case.

Comment: Nice catch, i forgot they were conditional. I think it's better to `guard` them

Comment: No problem, for the rest your answer is perfect.

Comment: You like my guard idea, as I can see :p

Comment: I __COPIED__ several parts of your answer __BUT__ the `guard` is my idea __:D__

Comment: You were gonna use pattern matching on the `Optional` enums! :p

Comment: No I suggested you pattern matching with `Optional` into the comment but my answer with `guard` was already posted. It was just another solution.

Comment: By the way congrats for the big contribution you are providing here on SO about swift.

Answer (score 1):

The problematic statement is `return (returnval)` because Swift compiler thinks that there is a pass through the if-then-else chain that does not result in assignment of `returnval`.

For example, if `chosen` is 3 and `rval` is 2, there would be no assignment.

Perhaps other parts of your program makes it impossible for `chosen` to be 3 at the same time as `rval` is 2, but Swift has no idea of that, so it reports an error. In order to fix the compile error, add an initial value to `returnval`.

If you are absolutely sure that your if-then-else chain enumerates all valid possibilities, set `returnval` to `-1`, and make an assertion about it being set to a non-negative value before returning:

```
var returnval = -1
... // your conditionals go here
assert(returnval >= 0, "Logic of determineWinner is broken")
return returnval
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `var returnval: Int = 0` (or another random number in case your if-else statements are exhaustive)

Answer (score 0):

**EDITTED**

## Problem Resolution

You're getting the initializer error because you haven't initialized `returnval` with `Int()` prior to setting.

## Code Improvements

Consider using a **computed property** to return the value of who won. I made the assumption in my code below, that the value 2 you were using inferred a tie situation based on your logic.

Here I created an **enumeration** to ensure the returned value is only handled in these particular ways you'd expect the outcome to mean. You can still access the `Int` values via the hash value on the enum case. Use `.rawValue` to do so.

It is important to try your best to avoid using `Int` values in this case because they can be other values.

In the code I included below I wrote you a set of `guard` statements to fail and return a `fatalError` message when the values checked do not allow the winner state to be determined.

**Improved Code**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class Result: UIViewController {

  var rval: Int?
  var chosen: Int?

  enum Winner: Int {
    case one  = 0
    case two  = 1
    case tie  = 2
  }

  var winner: Winner? {

    guard (rval > 0 || rval < 4) else {
      fatalError("rval out of bounds: cannot determine winner")
    }
    guard (chosen > 0 || chosen < 3) else {
      fatalError("chosen out of bound: cannot determine winner")
    }
    guard (rval != nil && chosen != nil) else {
      fatalError("rval or chosen are nil: cannot determine winner")
    }

    switch (chosen!, rval!) {
    case (let chosen, let rval) where chosen == rval: return Winner.tie
    case (1, 3): return Winner.two
    case (1, 2): return Winner.one
    case (2, 1): return Winner.two

    default:
      return nil
    }
  }


  @IBOutlet weak var wl: UILabel!

  @IBAction func PlayAgain(sender: AnyObject) {
  }
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    print(chosen)
  }
}
```

As a side note be sure to +1 the answers you like!

Comment: I'm going to combine our two answers together

Comment: Agreed, I like your switch statements

Comment: I like your use of optionals and computed properties. I returned `-1`. I feel dirty.

Answer (score 0):

### Returning an Int?

As others already said, the problem is that none of your conditions is met then `returnval` is not initialized.

You can use a switch statement + guard + computed property. Like this

```
var winner: Int? {
    guard let chosen = chosen, rval = rval else { return nil }
    switch (chosen, rval) {
    case (let chosen, let rval) where chosen == rval : return 2
    case (1, 3): return 1
    case (1, 2): return 0
    case (2, 1): return 1
    default: return nil
    }
}
```

> Please note I slightly changed your logic. Infact in my code if chosen and rval are both nil the returned value is nil. While in your code 2 is returned. You should change it, maybe adding another `guard` on top of my code. Something like

```
guard chosen != rval else { return 2 }
```

### Returning Int + Fatal error

If you know chose and rval will always be populated then

```
var winner: Int {
    guard let chosen = chosen, rval = rval else { fatalError() }
    switch (chosen, rval) {
    case (let chosen, let rval) where chosen == rval : return 2
    case (1, 3): return 1
    case (1, 2): return 0
    case (2, 1): return 1
    default: fatalError()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this much more swifty.

For instance... Why use `Int` to represent the different moves? Here I used an enum to represent the moves and the logic behind what wins...

```
enum RoShamBo {
    case Rock
    case Paper
    case Scissors

    func beats(opposingPlay: RoShamBo) -> Bool {
        return self > opposingPlay
    }
}

// I thought it made sense to make it Comparable.
// That way you can use the < or > operator to determine
// the winning move.
// I then used this in the function beats() above
extension RoShamBo: Comparable {}

func < (lhs: RoShamBo, rhs: RoShamBo) -> Bool {
    // this is required for Comparable
    // in this we return true if lhs loses to rhs

    // Scissors beat Paper
    return lhs == .Paper && rhs == .Scissors
    // Paper beats Rock
        || lhs == .Rock && rhs == .Paper
    // Rock beats Scissors
        || lhs == .Scissors && rhs == .Rock
}
```

Then all you need to do is wrap this up in some sort of `Player` and `Game` type thing...

```
struct Player {
    let name: String
    let move: RoShamBo
}

struct Game {
    func winner(player1: Player, player2: Player) -> Player? {
        if player1.move.beats(opposingPlay: player2.move) {
            return player1
        }

        if player2.move.beats(opposingPlay: player1.move) {
            return player2
        }

        // tie
        return nil
    }
}

let p1 = Player(name: "Oliver", move: .Rock)
let p2 = Player(name: "Geoff", move: .Scissors)

let game = Game()

let winner = game.winner(player1: p1, player2: p2)

print(winner)

//Output Optional(Player(name: "Oliver", move: RoShamBo.Rock))
```

Not a single Int was used in the whole thing and you can see exactly what the winning move was and who won etc...

Enums are really a lot more powerful than they are given credit for in Swift.