# Swift: Error -> Variable 'str' used before being initialized

Tags: ios, swift, function

I want to write a function that receives an integer type. The function prints the integers descending from the entered number to the value 0 as a string value separated by a space between each element.

```
func countDown(_ number: Int) -> String{
    var n = number
    var str : String
    while n >= 0 {
        str = String(n)
        print(str , terminator: " ")
        n -= 1
    }
    return str
}
var numbersAsString: String = countDown(5)
```

Comment: Are you just trying to print the countdown, or do you want the function to return "5 4 3 2 1 0"?

Comment: Imagine what is going to happen with `countDown(-1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable used before being initialized in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929471/variable-used-before-being-initialized-in-function)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As now , str is not initialized in its declaration.
Then the method will return “0”.
You better use an array of string in which you put all the number as string .
And you return the array values joined by “ “.

```
func countDown(_ number: Int) -> String{
    var n = number
    var array = [String]()
    while n >= 0 {
        array.append(String(n))
        n -= 1
    }
    let str = array.join(delimiter: “ “)
    print(str)
    return str
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that `str` is not guaranteed to have a value by the time you use it in the `print` statement.

You already have another answer showing you a solution with your existing code, but here's a more Swift-y solution:

```
func countDown(_ number: Int) -> String {
    guard number > 0 else { fatalError("Bad input") }
    (0...number).reversed().map { String($0) }.joined(separator: " ")
}

var numbersAsString = countDown(5)
```

First, it checks the input to make sure that it's valid for a countdown. Then, it uses a `Range` from `0` to the input number, reverses the numbers, maps them to their `String` values and then joins them.

Comment: Thank you for your help!